# Should I implement gevent on top of ThreadPoolExecutor() when running Flask app with Gunicorn?

Tags: flask, gunicorn, python-multithreading

I have a Flask application that utilizes concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() for handling concurrent tasks such as sending requests to external APIs.
Currently, I am running the Flask app with Gunicorn and have configured it to use three workers.

Recently, I heard about gevent and its potential to improve concurrency in Flask apps. I'm wondering if it's recommended to implement gevent on top of my existing implementation with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()?